# How do I pull value from external website by Element ID with Excel / VBA?

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'm trying to retrieve values from external websites by element ID using VBA and add them to my excel table. The website URL's are indicated in column A. Column B and C are for my retrieved values.

[URL example](https://socialblade.com/youtube/user/elgodelio)
Element ID name: "youtube-user-page-country"

[Excel Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1g7p.jpg)

Bellow is my poor attempt:

```
Sub getCountry()

 Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
 IE.Visible = False

 IE.navigate Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(A3).Value
 Do
 DoEvents
 Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

 Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
 Set Doc = IE.document

Dim getCountry As String

getCountry = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("youtube-user-page-country").innerText)

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(B31).Value = getCountry

End Sub
```

The code isn't working showing problems with object definition.
Could anyone give me tips on where I'm going wrong?

I've been a macro recorder user and the switch has quite a steep learning curve :-)

Thanks for any help !

Comment: What's the question? What's not working? Please read [ask].

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, made edits to try and improve and accord to best practices. Any constructive tips are always appreciated (as well as your time).

Comment: Great! Retracted close & down votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get what you are after. There were a few issues:

1. You want to use `getElementByID`.
2. Naming a string **getCountry** and the SubRoutine **getCountry** containing it is not a good idea. You can do it, but don't.
3. Always fully qualify your sheet references so you know what workbook and sheet you are working with

Here's the revised code, I have it working on my end.

```
Sub getCountry()
    Dim IE      As Object: Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Dim ws      As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim Country As String

    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .navigate ws.Range("A3").Value

        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop Until .readyState = 4

    End With

    Country = Trim$(IE.document.getElementByID("youtube-user-page-country").innerText)
    ws.Range("B31").Value2 = Country
    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: That's great! Just one little thing is that I'm looking for the code to apply to all rows, so to increment the range. I've tried adding Offset(n,0) to the ranges with:

Dim n As Integer
n = 0
For n = 0 to 100

With IE....
... IE.Quit
Next n

But I keep getting an error: Method 'Navigate' of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed.

Any ideas? I'm feeling dumb :-/

Comment: Set a range object, then create another to iterate each cell. Alternatively, you can use the `.Cells` property to iterate. There are tons of examples on how to do this on SO. If you are still stuck, please make a new question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to dump the data to your spreadsheet.

```
Sub DumpData()

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

URL = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=sbux&ql=1"

'Wait for site to fully load
IE.Navigate2 URL
Do While IE.Busy = True
   DoEvents
Loop

RowCount = 1

With Sheets("Sheet1")
   .Cells.ClearContents
   RowCount = 1
   For Each itm In IE.document.all
      .Range("A" & RowCount) = itm.tagname
      .Range("B" & RowCount) = itm.ID
      .Range("C" & RowCount) = itm.classname
      .Range("D" & RowCount) = Left(itm.innertext, 1024)

      RowCount = RowCount + 1
   Next itm
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks Joel!!!